# PHP Let function set a member variable OR let it return the result

Tags: php, conventions

I have been wondering about something and I was hoping someone could clarify for me.

Assume we have a class

```
class Test
{
    private $value;

    function first()
    {
        if("this"=="that") {
            $neededVariable = 1;
        }
    }
    function second()
    {
        $this->first();
        //I need to evaluate something that was done in function first
        if($neededVariable===1) {
            //do something
        }
}
```

Now what would be the best practice to do? As far as I can tell there are two options:

1. Let the `first()` function set the member variable with `$this->value = 1;` and access that variable with the `second()` function.

2.The `first()` function could return `$neededVariable`.

They both give the same result, but I am wordering if there is a best practice. Maybe one has better perfomance than the other, or simply because it's the convention to go for option 1/2.

Any answers are much appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A property persists on the object, a returned value is more ephemeral. You need to decide which you want. Does the value contribute to the *state* of the object? Or is it just a value which you need once but don't need to persist and/or you *want* to recalculate each time as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the result of first in $this means modifying the object's state. Using that simply to pass a result is bad design, as a reader of your code will assume that the modification of the object's state has some deeper meaning. Worse, calling second() would also modify the object's state in the same way that first() does - is this something a user of your code would expect?

If modifying the object's state is the *intended purpose* of first(), and it would be clear to the user that second() would have the same effect, then setting $this->value in first() and calling first() in second() is good design.

If you just want to share logic, however, simply write a function that just reuses the logic. That way, you can separate setting state from reusing the logic.

```
class Test
{
    private $value;

    private function evaluate() {
      $neededVariable = 0;
      if ("this"=="that") {
         $neededVariable = 1
      }
      return $neededVariable;
    }

    function first()
    {
       $this->value = $this->evaluate();
    }

    function second()
    {
        $neededVariable = $this->evaluate();
        if($neededVariable===1) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that up for me! It helped a lot for deciding if I should use a private member or using a function whenever I need a specific calculation that does not alter the state of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I think no.1 is better.

Because if you use no.2, each time you call second(), first() also will be called in func second.(bad for cpu when first needs a heavy cpu useage)

But no.2 has some good things too. every time you want to use func second, you should have called func first before unless $value will be null. This is bad if you want to use this class in different pages.

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach which you have mentioned we are just calling a routine(function) and the space for the member variable  which was created is already getting utilized so no more memory requirement , 
While in second  if  the value get returned from that sub routine a another  temporary variable will be needed to store that data .  They both have the same result but  you unknowingly you will be creating a one more memory block for that temporary variable in second approach.

```
    class Test
    {
        private $value;

        function first()
        {
            if("this"=="that") {
                $neededVariable = 1;
            }
    return $neededVariable;
        }
        function second()
        {
    //either you create a variable or use directly the function in if..      
   //both will require that temporary memory block.
            $var = $this->first();  //or if($this->first() == 1)
            if($var ===1) {
                //do something
            }

    }
```